# can clojure definterface extend another interface?

Tags: clojure

I want to translate the following code into clojure:

```
package com.example.orbit.hello;

import com.ea.orbit.actors.IActor;
import com.ea.orbit.concurrent.Task;

public interface IHello extends IActor
{
    Task<String> sayHello(String greeting);
}
```

how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply define this interface Java and use it from Clojure.

If you really want to do it in Clojure, though, that is possible as well, although you'll have to use `gen-interface` rather than `definterface`:

```
(gen-interface
  :name fully.qualified.IName
  :extends [whatever.it.INeedsTo]
  :methods
  [[methodName
    [fully.qualified.type.of.Argument1 …] ; NB. no `this' formal argument
    fully.qualified.ReturnType]])
```

For a real-world example, have a look at [this interface definition in data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl/blob/data.avl-0.0.12/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/avl.clj#L131) or [this one in ctries.clj](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/ctries.clj/blob/76c3c311820aa9ec6e073abe29defd63b1d1c3e3/src/ctries/clj.clj#L117) (the latter uses `:extends`).

The `<String>` part of `Task<String>` will not appear in the Clojure version – generics are a `javac` construct and do not exist at runtime on the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Michal! My preference is to be able to this in clojure as it makes for recompilation and testing very easy.